# Executing dynamic javascript from an ajax call

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, ajax

I have a web application that is powered by ASP.NET on the server side and Javascript/jQuery on the client side. I'd like to know if it's possible to make an Ajax call to an ASP.NET WebMethod and have the returned javascript code executed. For example (very simplified example):

My HTML:

```
<html>
    <head>
        <title></title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="divMessage"></div>
    </body>
</html>
```

In my C#:

```
[WebMethod]
public static string GetScriptCode()
{
    return "$('#divMessage').html('This is a test');";
}
```

In my javascript:

```
$(function() {
    var handler = function(msg) {
        var myScriptCode = msg.d;
        // I'd like $('#divMessage') to contain my message
    };

    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "Test.aspx/GetScriptCode",
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        dataType: "json",
        success: handler
    });
});
```

I'd like the javascript that is returned from my `GetScriptCode()` to execute. Any ideas how to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

using eval() is one option, but as everyone say eval is evil, don't use it.

I normally do it using a dynamic function like so:

```
var theCode = "$('#divMessage').html('This is a test');";

var F=new function (theCode);

return(F());
```

Sort of looks like reinventing the eval, but that's how I do it as of now.

Comment: Just out of curiosity, why is `eval` evil? Is it a security risk or something?

Comment: You can never verify the code you are executing with `eval`, this can be any malicious/dangerously harmful code, which you would otherwise never run on your app.